# Accepts button in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, button

I have an users model ( cliens and perfomers) and also cliens has an order. Perfomers could accepts this orders and i need to put accept button in show template of order.

```
<% if current_user.user_type == "perfomer" %>
<% if !@order.order_perfomer_id.nil? %>
<h1><%=@order.order_perfomer_id %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Accept order!", :name =>"accept" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And after this i check in controller

```
def show
if !params[:accept].nil?
@order.order_perfomer_id = current_user.id
end
```

Yes it doesnt work, because it is a wrong way. Can anyone help with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because `form_for @order` scopes the params as `[:order][:attributes]` if you use the form object in block and create an element using Rails's view helper methods. In your case, it's `f.submit "Accept order!", :name =>"accept"`.

So, to summarize that. Your controller line should be checking `params[:order][:accept]` instead of `params[:accept]`.

Comment: if i write @form_for it asked for all object attributes,i think i need to change form into a <% button_to.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def show
  if params[:order][:accept].present?
    @order.order_perfomer_id = current_user.id
  end
end
```

In such cases, when you are not sure about what's inside the `params` hash, you can print the contents of `params` inside the controller's action like this: `puts params.inspect`. That way, you can be sure, what's coming through and then you can grab the required params that you need to work with.

Comment: got an undefined method error [], any other solutions?